# Cant access router login page.connection refused

Tags: networking, router, putty, dd-wrt

I just installed wrt firmware (it was compatible with my **TPlink TL-Wr 740n**) and it installed successfully but now when I tried default getaway I can't access router login page.I tried PUTTY.I tried hard reset several times.**ipconfig /renew | Release** are both not working either.I verified several times that default gateway is 192.168.1.1.It's responding to ping but no login page.Any suggestions, please

[image]

[image]

Comment: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` indicates your router is refusing the connection.  This means the firmware you installed doesn't appear to have a web configuration enabled.  I strongly suggest you SSH into the device, upload the default stock firmware, and restart the process of moving to WRT

Comment: What firmware did you installed? Have you tried accessing your router via telnet (port 23) or SSH port 22)?

Comment: @Alex I can now access through SSH using PUTTY but I cant seem to find working command for enabling web GUI.

Comment: @Alex name of firmware "openwrt-ar71xx-generic-tl-wr740n-v4-squashfs-factory"

Comment: Here is a good tutorial on how to install a webGUI: https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/luci.essentials#  however I think you should follow @Ramhound's advice and start over.

Comment: @hackerred - The firmware you loaded doesn't have luci installed which is the reason the connection is being refused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before installing a third-party firmware, you should have
first ensured that you have the installation media for the router's original
firmware from the manufacturer, and also that you master the know how, or have the tools, to force its installation in a bricked router, just in case.

If the installed firmware was DD-WRT, its default username is *root* and default password is *admin*.
If these do not work, do a hard reset and try again.

If this does not work, reinstall your original firmware.
Assuming your router is the TL-WR740N V5, you can download its firmware
and installation utility from the [TP-Link Support site](http://www.tp-link.com/no/download/TL-WR740N_V5.html).
If your router is not the V5, search for it in the TP-Link site.

In the case that this also fails, and as you can access the SSH,
you can use the firmware and instructions found
in the page [TP-Link stripped firmware](http://www.friedzombie.com/tplink-stripped-firmware/).
Even if this revives your router, I would still reinstall over it
the firmware downloaded from TP-Link, just to be sure.

Comment: I understand everything you are saying and I have tp-link firmware but problem that's occurring now is that I can't enable web GUI as flash ROM is full so I'm trying to install it using  Ssh and can't find command for that

Comment: In that case, your router does not seem to have sufficient memory for DD-WRT, which is probably the reason for all your troubles. My best advice is to give up and return to TP-Link firmware.

Comment: that's exactly what I'm trying to do but without a Web-GUI it's sort of impossible for me

Comment: The TP-Link utility should be able to install over DD-WRT. If it fails, my last link has some suggestions you could try inside its zip file.

Comment: the problem is not having a GUI and I'm trying alternate methods.I tried it by uploading bin file to tmp folder on router but at end this error occurs.`Writing from /tmp/43.bin to firmware ...  [e]Failed to erase block
`

Comment: I hope that you don't also have a hardware problem with the RAM. Try to see if the problem is disk-space, as you might be able to free up some.

Comment: Since my answer solved the problem, you should mark it as accepted (use the V button).

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks to all for your help in resolving issues.The first clue I got was using SSH instead of telnet by @alex.Then I followed [This Link](http://techtrickszone.com/2017/05/02/openwrt-firmware-upgradation-with-ssh-command-with-piture/) and it was of some help but no firmware was working from maker's site and then @harrymc helped by providing that link of striped firmware's that actually worked and now my router is restored to default condition.